# Create a directory in IFS using mkdir procedure AS400/IBMi

Tags: c, ibm-midrange, mkdir, rpgle

I reached an issue this afternoon trying to create in RPGLE different directories in IFS using C procedures mkdir to do that.
But when I'm testing if my new folder exists with worklnk command I have the following error CPFA0A9 like what my folder doesn't exist but I can add new files and folder using IFS tools.

Do you have any ideas ?

regards :)

```
fullpath = '//home/usr/' + %trim(£p1.pNomProduit);

  If (not Ctrl_Dossier(fullpath));
    // create folder
    // owner authority 448 + group authority 56 + other people 7 = 511
    result = mkdir(fullpath:S_IRWXU+S_IRWXG+S_IRWXO);

  else;
    result = rmdir(fullpath);
  ENDIF;
```

my mkdir procedure:

```
D mkdir           PR            10I 0 ExtProc('mkdir')
     D   path                          *   Value options(*string)
     D   mode                        10U 0 Value
```

Comment: Is there any char else than a-z and 0-9 in `£p1.pNomProduit` ?

Comment: This may very well be a simple typo problem.  Your fullpath variable starts with `'//home'` instead of `'/home'`.

Comment: Actually when I write```//``` it means that I want to find a folder since the root of the IFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@player1st comment is correct, should be `'/home/usr/'`  not `'//home/usr/'`

Also what is the datatype for `fullpath`?  Really should be `varchar()` but if fixed length, you'll want to include `options(*TRIM)` on the prototype.  Otherwise, the directory name includes trailing spaces.

```
D mkdir           PR            10I 0 ExtProc('mkdir')
D   path                          *   Value options(*trim:*string)
D   mode
```

Comment: You're right ! thank you I forgot to add a %trim to my path variable so it created a folder with few trailing blanks, and then when I tried to find this folder with wrklnk command I didn't have any results because the path were wrong